# Subresource server hint header doesn't work

Tags: performance, google-chrome, http, nginx, spdy

Trying to use the subresource server hint, but seems it doesn't work.

On the screens below you can see the main page with "Link" headers and both resources are fetched later. And as you see the initiator is parser instead of headers received before any content parsed. So the result is the same as it was before we used this header :(

Any ideas why?

[image: Headers]
full sized : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ey2K.png

[image: DevTools Network Tab]
full sized :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHXCM.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This has been an open bug in the Chromium project since 2010:

   > The Link HTML element has a response header equivalent.  It follows
   > the form:
   >
   > ```
   > Link: <http://href.here/to/resource.html>;rel="prefetch"
   > ```
   >
   > we should support this header, specifically for rel types prefetch,
   > subresource & dns-prefetch.

   At the time of writing, the issue was last updated 2 days ago, 2014-10-28.
   Issue detail: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58456
2. According to [section 5 of RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5),

   > The Link entity-header field provides a means for serialising one or more links in HTTP headers.  It is semantically equivalent to the `<LINK>` element in HTML.
3. The [W3C wiki page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader) points out that

   > The HTTP link header allows metadata to be given without actually touching the resource in question
4. On [the relevant Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20018), a comment from 2011 states that processing the link header is

   > just a matter of connecting the HTML element.

Based on these these references, I would conclude that Chrome is processing this header as it would a `link` element in the `<head>`.

---

Since it doesn't break the page, I wouldn't lose any sleep over it... in Chrome [or Firefox](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/httplink/). Internet Explorer, on the other hand, [denied that they will add support](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/786562/implement-link-http-header) -- and I quote -- "we do not plan on fixing this issue given the limited use of the Link header we have seen on webpages."